# Can a tensor of rank-2 be diagonalized by two different set of basis?

Tags: tensors, matrix-calculus, diagonalization, change-of-basis

I have two inertia tensors for a body, both calculated in two different points of it, but both gave me a diagonalized matrix, is this possible? the tensor is a symmetric one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the identity matrix. Seems to be diagonalizable with respect to any basis.

**Additional** Just in case the other example is not enlightening. Consider the matrix
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2& 1\\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then by the spectral theorem we see that $A$ can be diagonalize by an orthogonal matrix, i.e.
\begin{align}
A = Q^T DQ.
\end{align}
Here by direct computation, we see that
\begin{align}
Q = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
However, we could consider
\begin{align}
A = \lambda Q^T D(1/\lambda)Q = P^{-1}DP
\end{align}
where we used the fact that
\begin{align}
P = \frac{1}{\lambda} Q.
\end{align}
Thus, we have infinitely many ways of diagonalizing $A$.

Comment: I see... I was trying to use your hint but this example is way more simple, thank you a lot!

Comment: this is only for rank two tensors with  symmetric matrices